# Can't Tranfer Session ID When trying to allow access to a page when logged in

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to create a login page where the user enters an access code, if correct it will redirect the user to the main index.php, I am trying to only allow access to the index.php page if the user has logged in, but it wont display when logged in.

Phpmyadmin:
[image: phpmyadmin]

Login.php Code

```html
<?php  
include("DB.php");  //database connection
 session_start();  
 if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
 {  
      if(empty($_POST["code"]))  
      {  
           echo '<script>alert("Code Feild is Empty")</script>';  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["code"]);  
           $query = "SELECT * FROM login";
           $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
           if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
           {  
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                {  
                     if(password_verify($code, $row["Code"]))  
                     {  
                          //return true;  
                         header("location:index.php");  
                     }  
                     else  
                     {  
                          //return false;  
                          echo '<script>alert("Wrong User Details")</script>';  
                     }  
                }  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                echo '<script>alert("Wrong User Details")</script>';  
           }  
      }  
 }   
 include("loginpage.html"); //log in forum
 ?>
```

Index.php code

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["ID"])){
?>
 //website code
<?php
  } else{
  echo "You Need To Enter the Access Code to enter the site";
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't pass anything to your `SELECT` query -- is there only the one row in your database?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yes their is only one row, as it the idea is to create an access code verification where in which the user loads the site enters the code then is allowed access into the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding

```
$_SESSION['auth'] = 1 ;
```

to login.php when the password gets checked.
then on index.php i added

```
if(isset($_SESSION["auth"])){
```

this fixed my problem